# iOS making a 2D array using NSMutable array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to make a 2D array like this

[[1,2,3],[94,22],[2,4,6],[1,3,5,6]]

What is the best way to do this for iOS using NSMutable arrays

Comment: ok yeah like an array of arrays then.

Comment: `C` does not describe "NSMutable arrays"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create a static 2D array with differently sized rows.

Perhaps you can use NSArrays instead of C arrays to achieve this.

edit:
This is tedious, but you can try:

```
NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil];
```

And so on for each array, then

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[mutableArray addObject:array1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither C nor Objective-C truly support 2D arrays. Instead, in either language, you can create an array of arrays. Doing this in C gives you the same effect as a 2D array of ints with 2 rows and 3 columns, or vice versa:

```
int foo[2][3];
```

You can do something similar in Objective-C, but since you can't create objects statically, and you can't fix the size of a mutable array, and NSMutableArray holds object pointers rather than ints, it's not exactly the same:

```
NSMutableArray *foo = [NSMutableArray array];
for (short i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    [foo addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@1, @2, @3],
                   @[@94, @22],
                   @[@2, @4, @6],
                   @[@1, @3, @5, @6]];

NSMutableArray *arrayM = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSArray *nextArray in array)
    arrayM addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:nextArray];
```